# powerpc disassemble instruction by its raw data

Tags: disassembly, powerpc

How can I disassemble some intructions from memory dump? I have only raw dump, objdump understands only object format.

My processor is PowerPC 440 (*PowerPC Book E Architecture*).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, objdump can disassemble raw binary just fine. Try this:

`objdump -m ppc -D -b binary -EB dump.bin`

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. `objdump -mpowerpc -D -b binary -mpowerpc -EB dumb.bin`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ xxd -p asm
3800000060000000
```

Using [devkitPPC](https://sourceforge.net/projects/devkitpro/):

```
$ powerpc-eabi-objdump --disassemble-zeroes -m powerpc -D -b binary -EB asm
```

Yields:

```
asm:     file format binary

Disassembly of section .data:

00000000 <.data>:
   0:   38 00 00 00     li      r0,0
   4:   60 00 00 00     nop
```